# I want only one component state to be true between multiple components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am calling components as folloews

```
{userAddresses.map((useraddress, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <Address useraddress={useraddress} />
              </div>
            );
})}
```

Their state:

```
const [showEditAddress, setShowEditAddress] = useState(false);
```

and this is how I am handling their states

```
const switchEditAddress = () => {
    if (showEditAddress === false) {
      setShowEditAddress(true);
    } else {
      setShowEditAddress(false);
    }
  };
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working about your code? Can you be more specific? Because right now the code you have posted just says that you are toggling a boolean state change. It has nothing to do with your question title about one state between multiple components.

Comment: I have got addresses array and i am mapping over them and calling address component which has a edit button on clicking that another component edit adresses opens up and if we click on edit for another address Component then i want to change showEditAddress of other components to false

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's better if you want to toggle between true and false to use the state inside `useEffect` hook in react.

`useEffect` will render the component every time and will get into your condition to set the state true or false.

In your case, you can try the following:

```
useEffect(() => {  if (showEditAddress === false) {
  setShowEditAddress(true);
} else {
  setShowEditAddress(false);
} }, [showEditAddress])
```

By using `useEffect` you will be able to reset the boolean as your condition.
Also find the link below to react more about `useEffect`.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: But this made component run in a infinite state

Comment: This will only re-render the component as the state change to check for the state and also will change the old state to the new one. as to change the old state you will need to re-render the component. that's the point of using useEffect

Answer (score 0):

It would be best in my opinion to keep your point of truth in the parent component and you need to figure out what the point of truth should be. If you only want one component to be editing at a time then I would just identify the address you want to edit in the parent component and go from there. It would be best if you gave each address a unique id but you can use the index as well. You could do something like the following:

UserAddress Component

```
const UserAddress = ({index, editIndex, setEditIndex, userAddress}) => {
  return(
    <div>
      {userAddress}
      <button onClick={() => setEditIndex(index)}>Edit</button>
      {editIndex === index && <div style={{color: 'green'}}>Your editing {userAddress}</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Parent Component

```
const UserAddresses = () => {
  const addresses = ['120 n 10th st', '650 s 41 st', '4456 Birch ave']
  const [editIndex, setEditIndex] = useState(null)

  return userAddresses.map((userAddress, index) => <UserAddress key={index} index={index} editIndex={editIndex} setEditIndex={setEditIndex} userAddress={userAddress}/>;
}
```

Since you didn't post the actual components I can only give you example components but this should give you an idea of how to achieve what you want.